# To prove some property "to stretch to some class of objects"

Tags: word-choice, word-usage, idiom-requests

While collaborating in the writing of a scientific paper, one of the co-authors wrote ".../... and we will prove it to stretch to some class", is it usual ?

The context is the following. 
"Then, we study in part 3 how to extend Radford’s theorem and we will **prove it to stretch** to the class of associative and commutative products."

**Last event** : After having interacted with the co-author and with regard to
the metaphor of mountain chains, the considered sentence was changed
for "Then, we study in part 3 how to extend Radford’s theorem and we will
prove it to stretch *across* the class of associative and commutative products".

Comment: It sounds  bit odd in isolation, but you can't expect a meaningful assessment unless you provide more context (without which I'm sure the question will simply be closed for *lack* of that context).

Comment: @FumbleFingers Thanks, I have (hopefully) given more context.

Comment: Possibly the writer was influenced by the preceding "infinitive marker" ***to** stretch*, but he's actually made what I would consider to be a grammatical "mistake" - it should be *prove it to stretch **to** [the other contexts]*.

Comment: Just to be clear, is the stretching here meant to be physical?  Or is this a metaphorical stretching in which the theorem itself is generalized to other applications?

Comment: @CandiedOrange No, it is just physical (well in terms of text length :), the theorem itself is not generalized, just stated in its largest setting.

Comment: Can anyone explain this downvote ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like @FumbleFingers commented, I believe a greater knowledge on the context is necessary. But I translate a lot of academic texts (english < > portuguese), and it seems to me that when they use the "prove it to stretch" expression it is strictly referring to the mentioned above: *"we study in part 3 how to extend Radford’s theorem"*. Meaning they have previously demonstrated a way to extend Radford's theorem, and they will now prove *how far it can be stretched*. (Taking the relation between the definition's of *extend* and *stretch*...)

It also sounds odd to me, grammatically, but that's the only way I can think of interpreting it in that sentence alone...

Comment: @Duchamp Gérard H. E. If you have to stretch a proof, it wasn't a proof. And you can't stretch a theorem. You can (if it is possible) extend its scope. Add a rider.

Comment: @DuchampGérardH.E.-  I have read the other comments and answers, and I think that there's a disconnect between the literal "stretch" meaning-- to lengthen-- and the usual English connotation, which is, "to lengthen beyond the typical."   In academic contexts, "a stretch," is an argument that is not quite convincing.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your comments and interest in the question (useful for me). Any other answer ? (I leave it open some more time)